# Авторизация через соц сети

Tags: авторизация

В чем смысл такой авторизации и как ее заменить стандартную(локальную) авторизацию на сайте?

Answer (score 1):

Может, это поможет? - [OAuth](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).

> OAuth — открытый протокол авторизации, который позволяет предоставить третьей стороне ограниченный доступ к защищенным ресурсам пользователя без необходимости передавать ей (третьей стороне) логин и пароль. Например, пользователь, который хочет предоставить сервису социальной сети доступ к книге контактов своего почтового аккаунта, не должен сообщать сети свой пароль от почты. Вместо этого он проходит авторизацию непосредственно в почтовом сервисе, который (с разрешения пользователя или администратора сервиса) предоставляет сервису социальной сети полномочия доступа к адресной книге.